# Mobile app - Configure backend server address

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm developing a packaged mobile html/js app. The backend server is on-premisse, so I dont know the servers address at build/publish time. What is the best/standard way to configure server address? Should I present a form with a field to users input server address and store this information locally?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want the user configurable address then providing the fields for input is the right approach obviously.

Other possible approaches are:

1. Using dns hostname (**server.yourdomain.com**) which you change to
   the IP of the server when you get one and your app always points to
   the hostname
2. Using a fixed point (**yourdomain.com/serverinfo.json**) where
   server's ip will be written along with other required data

It all depends on the use case, really.

Comment: This app will be publish in google play, but backend is on-premise, lets say company "A" or "B". I have seen apps presenting a input to user select a server address. I'm just not sure its right/only choice...

Comment: As I said, it depends what you need. If you do not really need to allow users to change the server, I would go with creating A zone on your domain (server.yourdomain.com), which would point to the IP of the server.